# How to Fetch ajax loaded website with CasperJS

Tags: html, parsing, phantomjs, casperjs

Hello i am trying to get a betting coupon from the web via scraping with casperjs and phantomjs. The page loads via ajax and prints a table with the data .The web site is : `https://www.pamestoixima.gr/UK/1/Print#market-group=12924.1&marketgroup-template=EVENTSPERDAY&marketgroup-longlist=1`
The data i'm interested in are lying in the table with the class : 'markets'
I've tried every code in the internet and i still cant get results. The page is getting scraped but it prints that 'The browser must have javascript enabled'

My code so far :

```
    var casper = require('casper').create();
casper.start('https://www.pamestoixima.gr/UK/1/Print#market-group=12924.1&marketgroup-template=EVENTSPERDAY&marketgroup-longlist=1', function() {
    this.wait(5000, function() {
        console.log(this.getHTML() );
   });
});
casper.run();
```

And the console output :

```
C:\Users\Bampis\Desktop\phantom>casperjs test.js
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/x
html1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd"><html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml
" class="ua-dom ua-strict ua-secure ua-windows ua-likegecko ua-safari ua-webkit"
><head><meta http-equiv="content-language" value="en">
                <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-
8">
                <title></title>
                <!--meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=10"/-->
                <link href="/Areas/Print/template_1_UK/template.css?ts=201504081
530" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen, tv, projection" charset="ut
f-8">
                <link href="/debug.css?ts=201504081530" rel="stylesheet" type="t
ext/css" media="screen, tv, projection">
                <link href="/Areas/.css/jquery-plugins.css?ts=201504081530" rel=
"Stylesheet" type="text/css">
                <link href="/Areas/Print/template_1_UK/print.css?ts=201504081530
" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="print">

                <script async="" src="//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js"><
/script><script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"
></script>
                <script type="text/javascript">window.jQuery || document.write('
<script src="/common/js/jquery/jquery.min.js"><\/script>');</script>
                <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.1/jqu
ery-ui.min.js"></script>
                <script type="text/javascript">window.jQuery.ui || document.writ
e('<script src="/common/js/jquery/jquery-ui.min.js"><\/script>');</script>

        <script src="/common/js/jquery/jquery-plugins.js"></script>
        <script src="/common/js/script.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
/*<![CDATA[*/
if(window.location.search != "" && window.location.search.indexOf('?debug') == 0
)
{
        document.write(unescape("%3Cscript type='text/javascript' src='/common/j
s/runtime-debug-201504021456.js'%3E %3C/script%3E"));
        document.write(unescape("%3Cscript type='text/javascript' src='/Areas/Pr
int/template_1_UK/components-debug-201504081530.js'%3E %3C/script%3E"));
}
else
{
        document.write(unescape("%3Cscript type='text/javascript' src='/common/j
s/runtime-201504021456.js'%3E %3C/script%3E"));
        document.write(unescape("%3Cscript type='text/javascript' src='/Areas/Pr
int/template_1_UK/components-201504081530.js'%3E %3C/script%3E"));
}
/*]]>*/
</script><script type="text/javascript" src="/common/js/runtime-201504021456.js"
> </script><script type="text/javascript" src="/Areas/Print/template_1_UK/compon
ents-201504081530.js"> </script></head>
        <body class=" print col1 lang-UK">
                <div class="c">
                        <div class="bg-content clearfix">
                                <div class="cc wrapper clearfix">
                                        <noscript>
                                                &lt;div class="noscriptDiv"&gt;
                                                        &lt;div class="top"&gt;&
amp;nbsp;&lt;/div&gt;
                                                        &lt;div class="middle"&g
t;
                                                                &lt;p&gt;Javascr
ipt is currently not active in your browser. Javascript must be enabled for this
 website.&lt;/p&gt;
                                                                &lt;p&gt;Javascr
ipt ╬┤╬╡╬╜ ╬╡╬ψ╬╜╬▒╬╣ ╬╡╬╜╬╡╧Β╬│╬χ ╧Δ╧Ε╬┐╬╜ browser ╧Δ╬▒╧Γ. ╬Ω Javascript ╧Α╧Β╬φ
╧Α╬╡╬╣ ╬╜╬▒ ╬╡╬ψ╬╜╬▒╬╣ ╬╡╬╜╬╡╧Β╬│╬┐╧Α╬┐╬╣╬╖╬╝╬φ╬╜╬╖ ╬│╬╣╬▒ ╬▒╧Ζ╧Ε╬χ ╧Ε╬╖╬╜ ╬╣╧Δ╧
Ε╬┐╧Δ╬╡╬╗╬ψ╬┤╬▒.&lt;/p&gt;
                                                        &lt;/div&gt;
                                                        &lt;div class="bottom"&g
t;&amp;nbsp;&lt;/div&gt;
                                                &lt;/div&gt;
                                        </noscript>

                                        <div id="plchcentre" class="centre place
holder">
                                                <div id="plchFlash"></div>
                                                <div id="plchcentrebox2"></div>
                                        <div class="hidden" id="BodyClassOverrid
eComponent1"></div><div class="market-list" id="MarketListContentComponent2" sty
le="display: block; "><img src="/indicator.gif" alt="Loading"></div></div><!-- .
centre -->

                                        <div class="print-buttons">
                                                <a class="button" href="/Areas/P
rint/template_1_UK/#" onclick="window.print(); return false;">Print</a>
                                        </div>

                                </div><!-- .c -->
                        </div>
                </div>
        <!-- Google Analytics -->
        <script src="/static/common/analytics/analytics.js" type="text/javascrip
t"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        //Built with PageBuilder v. 1.0.0.0
        var autoWiring = new Framework.AutoWiring();
        autoWiring.init(serviceConfiguration, componentConfiguration, dynamicCom
ponentConfiguration, componentPlacementMap, encodedXsltDocumentsMap);
        autoWiring.run();
</script><div id="GarbageCollector" style="display: none; "></div>


<div class="ui-tooltip ui-widget ui-corner-all ui-widget-content" id="warp-toolt
ip" style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; z-index: 200000; display: no
ne; "></div></body></html>
```

Answer (score 1):

As far I can see the page you mention above is fed with data from a XML file:

https://www.pamestoixima.gr/cache/evenuemarketGroupLimited/EN/12924.1-0.xml?1457949428105 (probably the timestamp in the query string has to do with some kind of logging, since even if you remove it, you get the same result).

So it's better to grab directly this file rather than mimic a browser's behaviour and get the rendered html.